# second call of seekg not working

Tags: c++, file-io

In my following code , I am counting the number of words , lines and then calculating the size of text file . The first use of `seekg` works fine after the first `while` loop but after the second `while` loop , it doesn't work . it gives values as shown in output .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std ;

int main(void)
{
    fstream  txtFile;
    txtFile.open("test.txt");

    if(txtFile.is_open())
    {
        printf("txt file is opened");
    }

    //number of words and lines in txt file
    int w=0 , l =0 ;
    int c , start , end;
    string s;

    while(1)
    {
        if(txtFile.peek() == -1)
            break;
        c = txtFile.get();
        if(c != txtFile.eof())
                    w++;
    }

    txtFile.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    while(getline(txtFile,s))
    {
         l++ ;
    }
    printf("no of words : %d , no of  lines: %d\n",w,l);

    //calculate the size of both the files
    txtFile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    start = txtFile.tellg();
    printf("%d\n",start);;
    txtFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
    end = txtFile.tellg();
    printf("%d\n",end);;

    return 0 ;
}


OUTPUT
txt file is opened
no of words : 128 , no of  lines: 50
-1
-1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last input operation causes the fail bit to be set. If you call `tellg` while this bit is set it too will fail. You need to call `clear()` before you call `tellg()`.

```
txtFile.clear(); // clear fail bits
txtFile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
```

Comment: +1 The difference is that first loop only sets `eofbit` while the second one sets `eofbit` and `failbit`. `seekg()` clears the `eofbit` automaticaly, but fails if any other flag is set.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Sir, can u please tell which "last input operation" you are talking about ? Also , please tell how do you come to know the fail bit is set or not ??

Comment: @CodeJack The call to `getline(txtFile,s)` and I know because the standard tells me so